# Fast Delegate Accessors without using DynamicInvoke()?

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, lambda, delegates

I'm recently developing a SQLite ORM, and I came across some issues about dynamic things, (I'm coding against C# 3.5). One of them is about how to get quickly a property value. I tried many different ways and one of them is really fast (almost fast as a native and hard-coded access) but the thing is that you need to use the generics while I would like just to provide the types. If I only provide types I'm stuck with a delegate (where only the slow and desperate DynamicInvoke Method is available) or using MethodInfo.Invoke()...

So I'm wondering is there any proper ways to get this Invoke() (instead of the DynamicInvoke) when I have a delegate. I though about casting the Delegate into a Func but it does not work.

Any tricks?

```C#
class Program
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        DummyClass dummyInstance= new DummyClass();
        dummyInstance.DummyMember = "I'm a Dummy Value!";

        Type typeDummyClass = typeof(DummyClass);

        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeDummyClass.GetProperty("DummyMember");
        MethodInfo methodInfo = propertyInfo.GetGetMethod();

        ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeDummyClass, "Instance");
        Expression expression = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, propertyInfo.Name);

        Type funcType = typeof(Func<,>);
        Type funcGenericType = funcType.MakeGenericType(typeDummyClass, propertyInfo.PropertyType);

        LambdaExpression lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(funcGenericType, expression, parameterExpression);
        Expression<Func<DummyClass, String>> expressionTyped = Expression.Lambda<Func<DummyClass, String>>(expression, parameterExpression);
        Delegate @delegate = lambdaExpression.Compile();
        Func<DummyClass, String> func = expressionTyped.Compile();

        TimeSpan timeSpanNativeAccess = new TimeSpan(0);
        TimeSpan timeSpanGetValueCachedAccess = new TimeSpan(0);
        TimeSpan timeSpanMethodInfoCachedAccess = new TimeSpan(0);
        TimeSpan timeSpanDelegateCachedAccess = new TimeSpan(0);
        TimeSpan timeSpanFuncCachedAccess = new TimeSpan(0);

        for (UInt32 i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatchNativeAccess = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var dummyNativeAccess = dummyInstance.DummyMember;
            stopwatchNativeAccess.Stop();

            Stopwatch stopwatchGetValueCachedAccess = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var dummyGetValueCachedAccess = propertyInfo.GetValue(dummyInstance, null);
            stopwatchGetValueCachedAccess.Stop();

            Stopwatch stopwatchMethodInfoCachedAccess = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var dummyMethodInfoCachedAccess = methodInfo.Invoke(dummyInstance, null);
            stopwatchMethodInfoCachedAccess.Stop();

            Stopwatch stopwatchDelegateCachedAccess = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var dummyDelegateCachedAccess = @delegate.DynamicInvoke(dummyInstance);
            stopwatchDelegateCachedAccess.Stop();

            Stopwatch stopwatchFuncCachedAccess = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var dummyFuncCachedAccess = func.Invoke(dummyInstance); // func(dummyInstance);
            stopwatchFuncCachedAccess.Stop();

            timeSpanNativeAccess += stopwatchNativeAccess.Elapsed;
            timeSpanGetValueCachedAccess += stopwatchGetValueCachedAccess.Elapsed;
            timeSpanMethodInfoCachedAccess += stopwatchMethodInfoCachedAccess.Elapsed;
            timeSpanDelegateCachedAccess += stopwatchDelegateCachedAccess.Elapsed;
            timeSpanFuncCachedAccess += stopwatchFuncCachedAccess.Elapsed;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("timeSpanNativeAccess = " + timeSpanNativeAccess.TotalMilliseconds + " ms");
        Console.WriteLine("timeSpanGetValueCachedAccess = " + timeSpanGetValueCachedAccess.TotalMilliseconds + " ms");
        Console.WriteLine("timeSpanMethodInfoCachedAccess = " + timeSpanMethodInfoCachedAccess.TotalMilliseconds + " ms");
        Console.WriteLine("timeSpanDelegateCachedAccess = " + timeSpanDelegateCachedAccess.TotalMilliseconds + " ms");
        Console.WriteLine("timeSpanFuncCachedAccess = " + timeSpanFuncCachedAccess.TotalMilliseconds + " ms");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class DummyClass
{
    public String DummyMember { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What do you mean by *you need to use the generics while I would like just to provide the types*? As for speed, compiling an expression to a dynamic method and creating a delegate from it is about the fastest method there is, short of instrumenting/AOP, and you already know about it. As an aside, your timing code won't work properly. The individual get operation takes too little time for Stopwatch to measure.

Comment: "So I'm wondering is there any proper ways to get this Invoke() (instead of the DynamicInvoke) when I have a delegate. I though about casting the Delegate into a Func but it does not work." is not clear enough?

In "short", my question is how to get a quick method to have the getter value. I'm just frustrated that the Delegates using Generics such as Action<T> or Func<T, TResult> can provide the access to the Invoke method with a efficiency close to the native access while using a simple Delegate just allows me to call the inefficient DynamicInvoke...

Comment: I partially agree with you about the bench-marking method (in particular about the duration of accessors actions to be properly measured). 

But here no matter how (covering an independent loop with a dedicated stopwatch for each technique or the way I did) lead to the same conclusions.

Comment: The benchmark is fundamentally borken.  The jitter optimizer will completely remove the dummyInstance.DummyMember property getter call since its value isn't used at all.  It cannot remove the delegate calls since it doesn't know what side-effects the delegate target method may have.  So you are comparing a delegate call against *no code*.  Of course it is slower :)  Your key mistake is to not use a profiler to measure *real* code.  When you do, you'll surely be taken a-back a bit how long it takes SQLite to read data off a disk.  Reflection.Emit is fastest, as used by Expression.

Comment: Yeah but it does mean that the comparison among the other methods (through MethodInfo and Delegates) is broken...
Also I'm not sure that this small optimization is actually happens when you do not check the "Optimize code" checkbox of the project running that short snippet of code (I admit that I did not check the IL code associated to...).

Comment: Oh and SQLite has nothing to do here, it's just a matter of how to get a super fast Delegate getter without using Generics.

I'm not the only one who stated that behaviours and performances. Many similar benchmarks have been done with similar conclusions.

Comment: Another benchmark example: [http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2012/2/4/reflection-vs-compiled-expressions-vs-delegates-performance-comparision](http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2012/2/4/reflection-vs-compiled-expressions-vs-delegates-performance-comparision)

About DynamicInvoke, I've already went through most of the stackoverflow posts dealing with that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I found a way to get the Invoke() method with the code presented here: [Faster way to cast a Func<T, T2> to Func<T, object>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169062/faster-way-to-cast-a-funct-t2-to-funct-object)

The trick is that C# 3.5 does not provide any variance stuff so you have to bring your own conversion when you are creating the conversion.

Consequently adding a UnaryExpression to bring conversion in order to get Func (for getter)

```
private static Func<Object, Object> GenerateAccessor(MethodInfo methodInfo)
{
    Type typeObject = typeof(Object);

    ParameterExpression @object = Expression.Parameter(typeObject, "Objet");

    UnaryExpression unaryExpression = Expression.Convert(@object, methodInfo.DeclaringType);
    MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(unaryExpression, methodInfo);
    UnaryExpression unaryExpressionBis = Expression.Convert(methodCallExpression, typeObject);

    Expression<Func<Object, Object>> epxressionFuncObjectObject = Expression.Lambda<Func<Object, Object>>(unaryExpressionBis, @object);

    return epxressionFuncObjectObject.Compile();
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see. You wanted a `Func<object, object>`, with a signature like `Invoke`. Certainly, this is the way to do it.

Comment: Yup I just wanted to avoid the DynamicInvoke() ;)

Comment: How would you do this same set up for a setter? just replace all the `Func` with `Action`?